# Dynamically adding attribute-directive in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do you dynamically add an attribute directive to a pre-existing element?

I've tried the equivalent of:

```
<div class="container">
    <svg class="canvas"> <!-- renders up to here -->
         <custom-directive>
             <g class="group"> <!-- directive template -->
                 <rect class="body"></rect>
                 <g class="content"></g>
             </g>
         </custom-directive>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Show us what you have tried first. 2) Give us an example of why you would want to do this, there is probably a better/easier way

Comment: I'm working with SVGs, as you can understand it is a pain in the ass. I can't create an element directive inside an svg, even though the template contains svg elements.

I had a look at "foreignObject" but I don't think it will work.